# C++ Doubly linked list - deleting element from the tail using pop_back()

Tags: c++, class, doubly-linked-list, function-definition, member-functions

My pop_back() function is supposed to remove the last element in a doubly linked list. However, my current code removes the last **two** elements rather than just one. I have set up my pop_front() function similar to this one, which works just fine. I am having trouble figuring out what I've done wrong.

Here is part of my linkedlist header with struct Node:

```
class linkedlist
{
private:
    struct Node{
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        element_type data;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    unsigned int numElements;
```

My pop_back() function from the public section of linkedlist:

```
void linkedlist::pop_back()
{
    if (empty())
        return;
    else {
        Node *delBack = tail;
        Node *nodeToDelete = delBack;
        delBack = delBack->prev;
        delBack->next = NULL;
        delete nodeToDelete;
        tail = delBack;
        numElements--;
    }
}
```

If the problem is not immediately obvious, then it's possible the error is buried somewhere else in the code. Still searching.

Comment: Nothing is jumping at me based on what you have shared.

Comment: @Ryan  Though the function is wrong nevertheless it deletes only one node.:) Continue to search.:)

Comment: *I have set up my pop_front() function similar to this one* -- That isn't the way you approach these linked list problems.  You write the function based on what you've drawn on paper, with the boxes representing the data and lines denoting the links.  You've written your `pop_back` without verifying this logic actually works by drawing on paper the correct approach.

Comment: @Ryan  Could it be hackers from Russia who delete one more node?:)

Comment: a small, complete example would be helpful.  i think your other code is doing something because, as Mikel F says, nothing is obvious.  the posted code should remove one node

Comment: It looks like it should crash/UB if there is exactly one node in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Though the function does not delete two nodes simultaneously nevertheless the function is wrong. It does not check whether `tail->prev` is equal to `nullptr` and it does not set `head` to `nullptr` when the list becomes empty. The function can look the following way.

```
void linkedlist::pop_back()
{
    if ( tail )
    {
        Node *nodeToDelete = tail;
        tail = tail->prev;

        if ( tail )
        {
            tail->next = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            head = nullptr;
        }

        delete nodeToDelete;
        numElements--;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was in fact somewhere else. My push_front() was not updating the tail correctly, so pop_back() was using a tail which was not properly lined up with the list. Thanks.